# uplaod image and video to amazon S3 (arm64 error)

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-s3, arm64

My code is for uploading videos and photos, and it is working fine but when I put arm64 to valid architectures it displays the following errors

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/clicktraders/Desktop/On Going Projects/VideoUploading/AWSRuntime.framework/AWSRuntime, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/clicktraders/Desktop/On Going Projects/VideoUploading/AWSRuntime.framework/AWSRuntime (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/clicktraders/Desktop/On Going Projects/VideoUploading/AWSS3.framework/AWSS3, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/clicktraders/Desktop/On Going Projects/VideoUploading/AWSS3.framework/AWSS3 (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonS3Client", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CLUploadService.o
      objc-class-ref in SyncViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_S3CannedACL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CLUploadService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_S3PutObjectRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CLUploadService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_S3TransferManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SyncViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in FirstViewController.o
  "_OBJC_EHTYPE_$_AmazonClientException", referenced from:
      GCC_except_table1 in CLUploadService.o
  "_OBJC_EHTYPE_$_AmazonServiceException", referenced from:
```

Kindly guide me whats wrong with that. @z3r0

Comment: Are you linking against a static library? Is the static library built for arm64. Is the library project added as a child project in you App project? If so, you may need to add arm64 to architectures of library target as well.

Comment: I am linking a static library.

Comment: Is arm64 in valid architectures of your library project, If you have one?

Comment: yup i  upload app to app store without adding arm 64 in valid architecture.but i got an following email "Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code." then after that i added arm 64 to valid architecture .after adding the errors occu

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. What I meant was, how are you linking against library. There are two ways:1) You have Library's XCode Project and you add it as sub-project to your app's project. 2) You add a pre-built libXYZ.a to your link phase and add ONLY header files to your search path. Which of these methods are you using?

Comment: i use 2nd way. just adding frameworks and classes by drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments:

In the case you are using pre-built libXYZ.a, your static library wasn't  compiled for 64-bit. You need a newer version. If you have source code, You can re-compile with support for 64 bit system.

Answer (score 1):

All your linked frameworks must have `64-bit` support. Your AWS framework version is old. You should at least have `AWS SDK for iOS 1.7.0`. It's the first version that supports 64-bit. Otherwise, your app won't be accepted to `AppStore`. You can get them from:

https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/iOS